# Issue while retrieving data using ADO.Net

Tags: c#

from my application I am retrieving data using ADO.Net classes.

```
 private DataSet GetData(string clientconstr,string actionparam,string userid)
 {
            DataSet dsData = null;

                SqlParameter[] objSqlParam = new SqlParameter[2];
                objSqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@ACTION", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                objSqlParam[0].Value = actionparam;
                objSqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@USERID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                objSqlParam[1].Value = userid;

                dbc = new dbClass(clientconstr);
                dsData = dbc.ExecuteNonQuery("SPLINV", "SP", objSqlParam);
}

class dbClass
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        string connectionstring = "";

        public dbClass(string conStr)
        {
            connectionstring = conStr;
        }

        public DataSet ExecuteNonQuery(string query, string querytype, SqlParameter[] objArrSqlParamas)
        {
            DataSet ds = null; 

            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
                con.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;

                if (querytype.Equals("sp"))
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                else
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;

                if (objArrSqlParamas != null)
                {
                    for(int idx=0;idx<objArrSqlParamas.Length;idx++)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(objArrSqlParamas[idx]);
                }

                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                    cmd.Dispose();
                if (da != null)
                    da.Dispose();
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return ds;
        }
}
```

Even though I am passing all the parameters to SP "SPLINV",I am getting below error in the GetData function.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'SPLINV'
>   expects parameter '@ACTION', which was not supplied.

"SPLINV" Sp was created like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPLINV
(      
@ACTION VARCHAR(50),      
@USERID VARCHAR(100)      
)
```

I just want to know why this issue happening even though I am passing all the parameters to SP and how to resolve this.

Comment: is `actionparam` null when GetData is called?

Comment: Hi Rene,In both parameters I am passing values.

Comment: Please remove all extraneous code and provide an [mcve]. It is impossible to tell whether the issue is caused by your input, your logic or your `dbClass` wrapper. A minimal example that reproduces this should span five lines of code. As @rene indicates, _if_ this code is exactly what you use and it performs as expected, then changes are that `actionparam` actually is `null`. You say you're "passing values", but did you actually set a breakpoint and inspect the variables?

Comment: Yes,I set the break point at the below line in the GetData function dsData = dbc.ExecuteNonQuery("SPLINV", "SP", objSqlParam); and observe the all the parameters values before execution of this line.In both parameters,values are there.

Comment: One more thing I observed this if we modified the sp and set null values to the parameters, I am not getting any such error.But i am not getting any data in the application.But actually from sp data is coming when I check at the database level.looks like passing values are not reaching to SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here :- if (querytype.Equals("sp"))

Equals is case sensitive. You are passing "SP" and checking for "sp". So the command get executed as text. Please go through the changed code.

```
 private DataSet GetData(string clientconstr,string actionparam,string userid)
 {
            DataSet dsData = null;

                SqlParameter[] objSqlParam = new SqlParameter[2];
                objSqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@ACTION", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                objSqlParam[0].Value = actionparam;
                objSqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@USERID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                objSqlParam[1].Value = userid;

                dbc = new dbClass(clientconstr);
                dsData = dbc.ExecuteNonQuery("SPLINV", "SP", objSqlParam);
}

class dbClass
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        string connectionstring = "";

        public dbClass(string conStr)
        {
            connectionstring = conStr;
        }

        public DataSet ExecuteNonQuery(string query, string querytype, SqlParameter[] objArrSqlParamas)
        {
            DataSet ds = null; 

            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
                con.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;

                if (querytype.Equals("SP"))
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                else
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;

                if (objArrSqlParamas != null)
                {
                    for(int idx=0;idx<objArrSqlParamas.Length;idx++)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(objArrSqlParamas[idx]);
                }

                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                    cmd.Dispose();
                if (da != null)
                    da.Dispose();
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return ds;
        }
}
```

Comment: Got the mistake.I am checking only from the parameters point of view.My issue resolved,Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the parameter directions to "Input"?

objSqlParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
objSqlParam[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;